# Hibernate datasource config based on login user credentials

Tags: spring, hibernate, postgresql

I am developing a Java webapp with Spring 3.2.1 and Hibernate 4.1.9 tied to Postgres Advanced Server backend (for row level security). The problem I am trying to solve is how to tie the webapp login user to the to the Hibernate session. To be specific, if user A logs in, then I want the webapp connection to the database to use A' credentials (only then I will be able to filter records that A has permissions to view / alter). Webapp & database users are validated against the same ldap server.

My config info is as follows:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.mycom.proj.model.A</value>
            <value>com.mycom.proj.model.B</value>
            <value>com.mycom.proj.model.C</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${db.hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Based on the above config, dataSource and sessionFactory beans are singleton's.

One approach I could take is to set the dataSource and sessionFactory to "session" scope. I am hesitant to take that approach for the following reasons:

a) If the database connection is at a session scope, then I cannot make use of connection pooling. (I think I may have to live with it)
b) I am afraid that setting the sessionFactory to session scope will mess up the Hibernate' cache mechanism.

Any thoughts / ideas about how I could solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to make all connections as an unprivileged user that has `NOINHERIT` membership of all the user roles. You then `SET ROLE` to the logged in user before running queries. If you fail to `SET ROLE` due to a programming error harm is minimized because you haven't granted the unprivileged user you're connecting with any rights and it hasn't inherited any, so it can't do anything.

It should be pretty easy to do this with servlet filters (if you use one connection for a whole request), CDI interceptors, a wrapper around your connection pool, using hooks provided by your connection pool implementation, or various other options to make sure it always happens.

It'd be nice if you could use `SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION` instead, but that requires a superuser connection. I don't recommend that applications use superuser connections even if they're just going to decrease their rights. One mistake could have very serious consequences.

I [wrote in a lot more detail about this in response to a DBA question a while ago](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/25400/7788).

Answer (score 1):

Usually connections pools handle per user pooled connections, so you only need an adapter to redirect `getConnection()` calls to `getConnection(user, passwd)`.

Spring provides one, see: `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter`

you can set the credentials on the `Datasource` via `setCredentialsForCurrentThread()` method in the login filter, for example.

Comment: This works great for smaller user counts, but would tend to fall apart when the number of users is significantly greater than the maximum number of connections that may be held in the pool. This approach might still be viable with a PgBouncer external connection pool in place to reduce connection overhead, since PgBouncer can change the active user of a pooled connection without disconnecting and reconnecting. You'd still pay the full Java-side cost of the new connection.

Comment: Good point, the connections will not be shared between users.